# keystone projet not getting updated while code changes

Tags: keystonejs

I'm new to keystone.js, but not new in the node and js framework world.

I installed keystone with the generator, I can run it with `gulp` or `node keystone` , in both cases the site is available on 3000, but updating js files in `/routes` or `/models` won't change anything until I re-run gulp or node... is that normal ?

I also ensured that I was in development mode with `set NODE_ENV='development'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with KeystoneJS.

By default neither `gulp` or `node` monitor for code changes.

If you want to monitor for code changes from within your `gulp` setup have a look at [gulp-watch](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch).

Otherwise, you can just use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) like so: `nodemon keystone.js`